# Why CredentialStore warning for Firebase user authentication in Java?

Tags: java, firebase

I'm trying some of the Firebase examples, specifically how to authenticate a user from in Java (standard JDK, not Android).

Each time I run the code, I get these warnings from (I presume) the Firebase API:

```
Sun Jun 28 14:29:58 BST 2015 [WARN] CredentialStore: Using no-op credential store. Not persisting credentials! If you want to persist authentication, please use a custom implementation of CredentialStore.
authenticated ok!
```

What is this referring to?  When it alludes to persistence, is it referring to persistence during the application session, or, between successive runs of the application?  How do I resolve this warning?

Here is the code -- it is based on the examples on the Firebase guides (note that account details have been obscured):

```
package firebase_reader;

import com.firebase.client.AuthData;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Firebase fbref = new Firebase("https://XXX.firebaseio.com/");  

        Firebase.AuthResultHandler authResultHandler = new Firebase.AuthResultHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData)
            {
                System.out.print("authenticated ok!\n");;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError)
            {

                System.out.print("auth failed:" + firebaseError);
            }
        };

        fbref.authWithPassword("YYY", "ZZZ", authResultHandler);

        try
        {
            while (true) { Thread.sleep(10000); }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the Firebase Android SDK, an Android application context is required when instantiating the Firebase client - and this context is used for automatically persisting authentication state *across application restarts*.

When using the vanilla Firebase JVM SDK, authentication state is not automatically persisted because there is no default mechanism for persisting this state across application restarts. If you don't care to have that auth. state automatically persisted, you can ignore the warning. Alternatively, you could implement the Firebase `CredentialStore` interface, but for a server-process this likely isn't needed.